# Set range and define named range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to define a named range (with Workbook scope) in VBA based on certain inputs to help figure out the cells that should be included in the range. To make it really simple, I have tried the following two with the errors indicated below. A, B, X, Y are found from some calculations

```
rName = <some string that decides the name>
Set TempRng = .Range(.Cells(A,B), .Cells(X,Y))
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rName, RefersTo:=Worksheets("Sheet1").TempRng
```

This gives me an "object or method not supported" error or something like that, on the Set TempRng line.

```
rName = <string ...>
Set TempRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(A,B), Cells(X,Y))
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rName, RefersTo:= <blah blah...>
```

This gives me an "application defined or object defined error" on the same line.

Can you please help me find the correct way to define this range?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bit more direct.

```
TempRng.Name = rname
```

Or you can even directly assign the name without using variable.

```
TempRng.Name = "myrangename"
```

The scope of the name is `Workbook` just in case that is critical in your needs. HTH.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't think there is any problem with assigning a name. In both cases, as I debug, I get an error on the Set TempRng line.

Comment: yeah sorry, i miss-read your post (where you clearly said it was the "set" lines that were failing). See my edited/revised answer above :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Check the values of A, B, X and Y first. Your syntax is correct but make sure you have the correct values for all variables used. If one returns error or a string (for A and X) at least, it will fail. Once you've check that all values are valid values, I don't see any reason for your code to fail. Except with what Simon posted regarding the use of `With Statement`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Refersto:="=" & TempRng.Address
```

Or more directly (as L42 says)

```
TempRng.Name = stName
```

To set your range make sure you've included "With" before you start "."ing things

```
With wsWhatever
    Set TempRng = .Range(.Cells(A,B), .Cells(X,Y))
end with
```

Comment: I will try that once I get past the Set TempRng line. Can you tell me how I should set the range itself (I mean the extent)?

Comment: Oh ok, try explicit cell references like you did above i.e.

Set TempRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(A,B), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(X,Y))

Or just:

With Worksheets("Sheet1").
   set TempRng = .Range(.Cells(a,b),.Cells(b,c))

Maybe you left out the "With" in the top one, and left out the Worksheet object for the second one?

Comment: If you use actual numbers in place of the variables, and it works, then it's the variables giving you issues.