# VBA Excel the name for range doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to define the name for my range.

I tried both solutions and none of them was working.

The first one was:

```
    With Range("M27:R40")
    .Merge
    .BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
    .Value = UCase("legend")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Name = "LEGEND"
    End With
```

The second one:

```
 Range("M27:R40").Name = "LEGEND"
```

I am confused, because as per the solutions below:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/name-a-range-in-vba-should-be-easy.26288/
[Set range and define named range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489982/set-range-and-define-named-range-in-vba)
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-define-named-ranges.378789/

it should work.

I get the name M27 instead which corresponds to the very first cell from the top left.

Is it something I've forgotten?

Comment: Works for me - after running that first one if I type `? activeworkbook.names("LEGEND").refersto` in the Immediate pane I get `=Table1!$M$27:$R$40`  (the sheet name is Table1)

Comment: "I get the name M27 instead" how exactly do you "get" that ?  Where/how are you viewing it?

Comment: Please, try the next way: `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LEGEND", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("M27:R40").Address`. It will certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

You can *set* a name with `Range("M27:R40").Name = "LEGEND"` (the first attempt you do is exactly the same). There are many ways to check this:

- Go to the Name Manager (on Formulas Ribbon), you will see the Name listed there.
- You can select the name from the dropdown at the top left (where the cell address is displayed)
- You can enter `? Range("LEGEND").address` in the immediate window of the VBA editor (or `Debug.Print Range("LEGEND").address` as statement in your code.

However, you can't read the name of a range using `Range("M27:R40").Name`. If the range holds a name, you will get the address of the range (don't ask me why) (okay, now I know, see Update), else you will get a runtime error (1004). But I cannot think about a case where this should be necessary.

**Update** As TimWilliams mentioned as comment: `Range("M27:R40").Name` returns a `Name`-object, and the default property of a Name is the address of it.

```
With Range("M27:R40")
    Debug.Print .Name       ' Will print the address
    Debug.Print .Name.Name  ' Will print the name of the Name object
    ' Or:
    Dim n as Name
    Set n = .Name
    Debug.print n.Name, n.Address
End With
```

Note that a name that is created this way is defined on *Workbook* level - equivalent would be the statement that FaneDuru listet in the comments:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LEGEND", _
        RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("M27:R40").Address
```

You can also declare a name of *Worksheet* level, the syntax is similar:

```
ActiveSheet.Add Name:="LEGEND", _
        RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("M27:R40").Address
```

(you need names on worksheet level if you have multiple sheets that have same name definitions).

If you want to read *all* defined names of a workbook or sheet, you can iterate the `Names` properties:

```
Dim n As Name
For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
    Debug.Print "Book:  ", n.Name, n.RefersTo
Next

For Each n In ActiveSheet.Names
    Debug.Print "Sheet: ", n.Name, n.RefersTo
Next
```

Comment: "If the range holds a name, you will get the address of the range (don't ask me why)" - `Range("M27:R40").Name` returns a `Name` object, and I'd guess the default property of that object is `RefersTo` (the associated range address in this case)   `Range("M27:R40").Name.Name` would give you the name.

Comment: @TimWilliams  You are right. I will update my answer